# What are Euclidean-normalized differential source counts?

Tags: observational-astronomy, definition

I would like to know what the **Euclidean-normalized** and **differential** source counts mean in "Euclidean-normalized differential source counts".

It would be great to hear a) a clear definition and b) an explanation on university student level.

The term is used in many papers. For instance, in the abstract of Grant et al. 2010:
[The DRAO Planck Deep Fields: The Polarization Properties of Radio Galaxies at 1.4 GHz](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...714.1689G/abstract)

Comment: "Differential" number count refers to the number between flux density S and dS. I think "Euclidean-normalized" just refers to the fact that the Stokes vector is normalized, using Euclidean geometry. But I haven't heard the term before, so I'll let some else answer.